# How to calculate average?

Tags: file, file-io, python-3.4, word-count, python-3.5

I need to write a function that counts all the words in a file and prints the average length of words.
(Punctuation marks musts be removed.)

```
def average(fileName):
   infile = open(fileName,'r')
   wordcount = {}
      for word in infile.read().split():
         if word not in wordcount:
         wordcount[word] = 1
      else:
         wordcount[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the workcount array after running the for loop, you can get the number of words.
I think the next step is to calculate the letters in your text file.

```
with open('text.txt') as counting:
print Counter(letter for line in counting 
              for letter in line.lower() 
              if letter in ascii_lowercase)
```

After that, you can get the average length you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
import re

non_word_chars = re.compile('\W+')
nr_of_words = 0
total_length = 0
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for word in f.read().split(" "):
        word = non_word_chars.sub('', word)
        nr_of_words += 1
        total_length += len(word)

print(round(total_length / nr_of_words))
```

Both time and memory efficient, since it doesn't involve constructing a dict and running over it again to calculate the average.